# spacemacs+helm search up a directory

Tags: helm, spacemacs

I am a fairly new Emacs user and just switched to using Spacemacs instead of trying to do all of the Vim configuration myself. It included a whole bunch of packages that I had not been using before, including Helm. I am willing to bet that I am missing something completely obvious, but I can't figure out how to search up a directory for file names without leaving the Helm search results.

#### What I am doing:

- I type `:e <TAB>` and get a list of filenames.
- I see I am in the wrong directory and type `../` to go up a directory
- Helm shows me anything in the current directory with any two characters followed by `/`

#### What I want to happen:

- I type `:e <TAB>` followed by `../` or some other simple sequence
- Helm shows me the contents of the directory above my current location

#### Similar behavior

I see that I can type `:e ../<TAB>` to get the contents of the directory above me or that I can hit `<ESC>` followed by `../<TAB>` but these both hide the search result window which I find a minor annoyance.

I feel that this is simple enough that I must be missing something. Is there a way to get this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which helm command you are using, but if you want to only display files of a certain directory you should try `helm-find-files`.
You can get to the contents of the directory above with the predefined shortcut `C-l` within the `helm-buffer`. It's also possible to navigate through your filesystem with arrow keys.

If you already know the name of the file you are looking for, I would recommend the command `helm-for-files`. However it doesn't always work properly, when using `locate`.

Comment: `helm-find-files` looks like exactly what I want. Upon further investigation it looks like that wasn't a helm command at all, it was `evil-ex-completion`. For some reason towards the bottom it displays `HELM-Completion-at-point`. `helm-for-files` looks promising as well. Thanks.